# Jmeter sends 3 requests when duration and thread per second is set 1

Tags: jmeter

Following are the params,

[image]

in the above scenario, I expect 2 threads but i see 6 threads 
below is the output,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each JMeter thread executes all [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) (or other) samplers under the Thread Group as fast as it cat. How many samplers will be executed given 2 seconds test duration depends on your application response time.

If you need to limit the throughput to certain value (i.e. 1 request per second) you will need to add [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) to your Test Plan and configure the target throughput to be 60 requests per minute.

[image: Constant Throughput Timer]